# Using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier causes images used as a repeating background to leak out of the cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

Am trying to use 3 images as the background for a cell. a top image, a middle (repeating image) and a bottom image. If I use a dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier then it works fine, however as soon as I start scrolling the table then the images don't stay inside the cell.

See attached image.

http://theutherfish.co.uk/iosss.png

This is the troublesome code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellidentifier"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier"];
}
```

This works fine, but I assume it is a memory hog.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

What would be the best way to have the best of both worlds? i.e. it working and not being memory intensive.

**UPDATE**
*complete cell for row at index path function*

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellidentifier"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier"];
}

UIImageView *img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 0.0, 310.0, 8.0)];
img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"];

UIImageView *img2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 8.0, 310.0, [PullRefreshTableViewController heightForExpandingCell:text])];
img2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"middle.png"]];

UIImageView *img3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, [PullRefreshTableViewController heightForExpandingCell:text] + 8.0, 310.0, 8.0)];
img3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tempbottom.png"];

[[cell contentView] addSubview:img1];
[[cell contentView] addSubview:img2];
[[cell contentView] addSubview:img3];

return cell;
```

Comment: Your first sample of code is not a "memory hog", it is the way you are supposed to re-use cells. However, you should probably be doing more work inside that block - like adding the background image. Please can you include the whole cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Agreed, it was the second piece which I thought may cause memory issues. Have updated the code to show the rest of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise using a single stretchable image as your cell background, and adding this in a single imageview (with the appropriate resizing masks) only when creating the cell (I.e. when cell== nil).

You then adjust the height in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

At the moment you are adding the image views every time a cell is reused, so you end up with dozens of them in each cell, and they are all different heights, so it looks a mess.

If the stretchable image doesn't work for you, you should look into creating the image views once only as stated above, and simply adjusting the frames when the cell is re-used.

Alternatively, since your image looks like nothing more than some grey rounded corners, look into CALayer's borderWidth, borderColor, borderRadius properties.

Comment: The picture isn't very good quality, but the cells are meant to have a drop shadow. Which is my reason for using images instead of code for the background. I will look into your suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: You can do a shadow with CALayer as well. It really sounds like the way to go for you.

Comment: Just had a play with CALayer in a test project and it seems really easy to use. Will apply this to my project later and hopefully it goes together nicely. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you find that scrolling looks poor with CALayer drop shadows, add a shadowPath to the layer - this really improves the performance.

Comment: It was jittery at first but using a the shadowPath really helped. Thanks again.